# jquery datepicker range (mindate maxdate) is not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker, range, maxdate, mindate

I'm trying to set a range for a jquery datepicker that I have on my form but when I open the form it allows me to select any date.

```
  <input class="span2 datepicker" name="tw#local#changeRequest#DeliveryDate" type="text" id="dp1">


 <!-- jQuery -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<#=tw.system.model.findManagedFileByPath('jquery-1.7.2.min.js', TWManagedFile.Types.Web).url;#>"></script>

 <!-- Datepicker Script -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<#=tw.system.model.findManagedFileByPath('bootstrap-datepicker_new.js', TWManagedFile.Types.Web).url;#>"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });

 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, it should be done like this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('option', {minDate: <some date>, maxDate: <some date>});
```

What you are missing is that you should set them using 'option'.

Comment: What you are missing is that you should set them using 'option'. - This did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
            maxDate: '0'}),
```

Use `'0'` for select max date today

You can also reference [jQueryUI Api](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
                maxDate: '+1m',
                minDate: '-20d',
                });
```

When min and max date are expressions they should be as strings and properly defined. [Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-maxDate)  is link for jquery ui datepicker MaxDate section.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing, you might have noticed that already, but
your selector is searching for ID as "datepicker".
Whereas, your datepicker is your CLASS.
So I think you need to change from 
"#datepicker" to
".datepicker".

Answer (score 1):

You can also test this.

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
});

$('#datepicker1').on('change', function() {
  $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
    startDate: $('#datepicker1').val()
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just add in controller if you are using angularjs $scope.today = new Date()

and in html min-date="today"

Answer (score 0):

When implementing the daterangepicker, I would receive a NaN value in the calendar every time I set both minDate & maxDate to a date. Despite working when I code them separately, they would prompt the said error when running together. I found out that if I added startDate & endDate, the calendar will no longer display NaN.

```
<script>
        let first_date = "{{first_date}}";
        let last_date = "{{last_date}}";

        console.log(first_date);
        console.log(last_date);
        $('#picker').daterangepicker({
            opens: 'right',
            timePicker: true,
            timePicker24Hour: true,
            minDate: first_date,  // with only minDate & maxDate, NaN value in the calender 
            startDate: first_date,   // startDate & endDate highlights the date range and prints values in calender 
            endDate: last_date,
            maxDate: last_date,
            locale: {
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH00'
            }
        }, function (start, end, label) {
            $('#start').text(start.format('DD-MM-YYYY HH00'))
            $('#end').text(end.format('DD-MM-YYYY HH00'))
        })
</script>
```

To briefly give context, I am developing a web portal using the Flask framework. The {{first_date}} is a jinjja syntax that was transferred from another web page.

To understand more about daterangepicker.js functionality, the link below will tell you all there needs to know about it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5QA8N4tQwg&ab_channel=CodeTube