# maxDate and minDate not working in Jquery Datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, bootstrap-datepicker

All other attributes like format ,`autoclose` etc are working, but `maxDate/minDate` is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using `bootstrap-datetimepicker`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#fdate").datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    pickTime: false,
    startView: 'month',
    minView: 'month',
    autoclose: true,
    maxDate: '0'
  });
});
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899472/jquery-datepicker-range-mindate-maxdate-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it suppose to be a date value. And also it seems you forgot to use the `option` in it.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('option', {minDate: <some date>, maxDate: <some date>});
```

Please have a look [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate).

Answer (score 0):

-> At first see that have you imported the correct path for **bootstrap-datetimepicker**

```
$('#date').datepicker('option', { minDate: new Date(startDate), maxDate: new Date(endDate) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nargis ,Rajesh & sibeesh for your Quick replies..

I Solved the problem ..

The problem was `maxDate` and `minDate`  are attributes used in some other plugin (i think **jquery** datatime picker) . as I am using an old **Bootstrap** plugin ,The valid attributes are `startDate` and `endDate`

The worked code is below

```
$(function() {
    $( "#fdate" ).datetimepicker(
      {
         format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        pickTime: false,
        startView: 'month',
        minView: 'month',
        autoclose: true,   
         startDate: '-1d',//previous date
         endDate: new Date()//current date
      });
});
```