# jQuery Datepicker minDate is not working in bootstrap

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set a minDate for a jquery datepicker. but itz is not working.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    minDate: new Date(),
    clearBtn: true,
    multidate: false,
    multidateSeparator: ",",
    toggleActive: true
});
```

Comment: please format your question properly

Comment: What is the error you are getting in the console? Also, can you create a fiddle / jsbin reflecting the problem? @VincyJoseph

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899472/jquery-datepicker-range-mindate-maxdate-is-not-working

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For jquery datepicker use:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0
});
```

For Bootstrap versions use:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
     startDate: new Date()
});
```

Comment: Thankz it worked. I'm using bootstrap version bt i'm trying to use jquery minDate

Comment: Wow thank you. I was driving myself crazy trying to use the jQuery API, only to learn from this that I was actually using the Bootstrap version. :)

Comment: yeah thanks a lot, even i came to know about this now..thanks again :)

Comment: It looks like the Bootstrap version (now called Tempus Dominus) has changed at some point and now uses minDate as well: https://getdatepicker.com/5-4/Options/#mindate

Comment: Perfect answer!!! made my day :) +1

Answer (score 5):

In newer bootstrap datepicker version use below method

```
limiting end date **eg** +1d, +3m, +5y , -1d , -3m, -5y
limiting start date **eg**  +1d, -23d, +3m ,2y, -2y 
$('#dob').datepicker({
            fautoclose: true,
            startDate: '+1y',
   });

 $('#dob').datepicker({
            fautoclose: true,
            endDate: '-18y',
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

to disable past dates use startDate instead of minDate.
like this...

```
$('#checkinDate').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: new Date()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change minDate to 0

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    minDate: 0,
    clearBtn: true,
    multidate: false,
    multidateSeparator: ",",
    toggleActive: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to jQuery datepicker api doc http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate, if you want to set today as minDate then minDate should be 0.

here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0dn4mtxn/1/

Try this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    minDate: 0,
    clearBtn: true,
    multidate: false,
    multidateSeparator: ",",
    toggleActive: true
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use php date function like this:

this is workingg..↓

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#Sdate').datetimepicker({
            minDate:'<?php echo  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>'

          });
       });
```

or  you can use this

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#Sdate').datetimepicker({
            minDate: new Date()

          });
       });
```

Comment: PHP is not part of the question.

Comment: if you working with php you can use above code .and your working with only Jquery You can Use Below Code now u can understand.....